# How to make multiple iframes with same src in the same page load independently?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I am building a Wordpress website,there is a webpage that contains multiple iframes wth same src.When i refresh the webpage all iframes show the same content,but it should show  different content based on the value passed by using session(method for passing values from one php file to another php file) from where the iframe is defined to where iframe src is defined.The iframe is defined in a plugin file and iframe src is defined as a template in theme folder.
So how to load multiple iframes with same src load independently?